# How to export multiple parameters in "module.exports"?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to export multiple parameters in `module.exports` object. Basically a constant and a function. But I obtain the following error:

> TypeError: add is not a  function.

First File:

```
        const name = 'Mike'

        const add = function (x,y){
            return x+y
        }

        module.exports = name,add();
```

Second File:

```
        const add = require ('./utils.js');
        const name  = require ('./utils.js');
```

Comment: `exports.name = name;  exports.add = add;` or `module.exports = {name, add}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make `module.exports` an object instead.

```
const name = "Mike";
const add = function(x, y) {
  return x + y;
};

module.exports = { name, add };
```

and

```
// destructure the names out...
const { name, add } = require("./utils.js");
// name and add are now available

// or require the module...
const utils = require("./utils.js");
// and then use utils.name, utils.add
```

Answer (score 2):

[`module.exports`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) is the object that's returned as the result of a `require` call.

```
const name = "Mike";
const add = function(x, y) {
  return x + y;
};

module.exports = { 
    name, 
    add 
};
```

now you can use this module in other modules by either the following ways

```
// using destructuring method
const { name, add } = require("./utils.js");

// or by requirng the whole file 
const utils = require("./utils.js");

// you can then use it like 
utils.add();

// consoling the variable name in utils module
console.log(utils.name);
```

[`Object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) can be referenced here.